# Re-sizing Raster file pixels

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, raster-calculator, jpeg-2000

I have 2 JP2 aerial imagery files that are incorrectly sized. They are 100x larger than the other aerial images but correctly geo-referenced (starting x, y co-ordinates).

I believe the issue is their defined pixel size ( 12.5, -12.5 ) as the other aerial imagery files have pixel sizes of: ( 0.125, -0.125 ).

I have opened the JP2 files up in notepad and changed these parameters but it corrupts the file or saves it as text. Dos anyone know what Raster tools in QGIS I can use to remedy this or any other techniques?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the georeferencer plugin and set the appropriate transformation to scale your two images: [http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_georeferencer.html](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_georeferencer.html/)

Comment: Which transformation would you recommend in this case?

Comment: No worries I have worked it out, thanks for your help.